R: Convert string to time lapse in seconds
Is there a way, in base R, to (try to) convert a string that may contain time-lapse information into seconds?
What I mean is some way where strings like '30 min', '1800 s', '0.5 h', '00:30:00' would all be converted to 1800. The idea is similar to what the Linux command at does when it interprets time information.
Similar question is this, but in my case I'm interested in time lapses, not time points (dates), and I don't know beforehand the time format used in the string.
Cheers!

Is there at least uniformity in digit space unit, well except for that digit colon digit colon digit  (unit implied). strsplit(tlapse, split = c(' ', ':')), then multiply first result by interpolated unit, and then there's that xx:yy:zz...

The short answer is yes, there is a way, but no predefined function to do this directly in R. You can write a function that scans the strings for m,s,h,min etc and then extract the number and multiply accordingly. The same with strings that contain :, but multiply based on position.

Assuming that the patterns shown are the only ones that appear determine if it needs difftime or a multiplier and apply the indicated one.  If additional suffixes are possible they can be appended to mult.
toSecs <- function(x) {
  code <- gsub("[0-9. ]", "", x) #s, min or h
  mult <- c(s = 1, min = 60, h = 3600)
  ifelse(grepl(":", x), 
    as.numeric(as.difftime(x, unit = "secs")), 
    as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x))  * mult[code]
  )
}

toSecs(x)
## [1] 1800 1800 1800 1800


Possibly share both implementations as the drive to concise in toSecs masks the reasoning in f, which was quite useful to think about.

Have completely revised.  Now vectorized.

Then I refer future readers to 'edits' to examine the evolution to vectorized.

I don't think the older ones are of interest.  A vectorized solution is just superior.

No argument here, but rare to find worked example from 'first thoughts' to 'fully vectorized', so concisely documented. My first thought was strsplit...

Thank you! also to @Chris for the comments to my question and this answer. Important for me was also to be aware that there is no built-in function that does this kind of "time expression" recognition.
